# Excel #VALUE! error when selecting a subset from a range using INDEX : INDEX or SEQUENCE based on calculated start, end values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

This is an hypothetic sample to show the following Excel odd behavior in several situations, where a subset of a range is selected via `INDEX:INDEX` or `INDEX` and `SEQUENCE`, where `start` and `end` positions of the subset of the range or the sequence are *calculated* via `INDEX` or `FILTER`.

The scenario is the following: I have an input range with values: `{1;2;3;4}` in the range: `A1:A4` and I want to sum the range from `2` to `4` with the expected result `9`, but to illustrate the point, I am going to calculate such numbers checking even condition. The following formula considers several use cases:

- **CaseA**, **CaseC**: Obtain the subset via  `INDEX(a,start):INDEX(a, end)` where `start` and `end` are calculated field and `a` refers to the input range.
- **CaseB**, **CaseD**: Obtain the subset via `INDEX(a, SEQUENCE(rows,, start)` where `rows` and `start` are calculated fields and `a` refers to the input range.

As part of my research and trying to find workarounds I use two ways for calculating the `start` and `end` of the subset:

- Using `INDEX` represented with names with the suffix `X`.
- Not using `INDEX` represented with names with the suffix `Y`. For example `XLOOKUP` or `FILTER`.

Here is the formula that covers **four** scenarios via `VSTACK/HSTACK` to compare all of them in a single call:

```
=LET(a, A1:A4, even, FILTER(a, MOD(a,2)=0),
    startX, INDEX(even, 1), endX, INDEX(even,2),
    startY, XLOOKUP(2, even, even), endY, FILTER(even, even > startX),
    caseA, IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(a,startX):INDEX(a, endX)), "ERROR"),
    caseB, IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(a, SEQUENCE(endX-startX+1,, startX))), "ERROR"),
    caseC, IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(a,startY):INDEX(a, endY)), "ERROR"),
    caseD, IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(a, SEQUENCE(endY-startY+1,, startY))),"ERROR"),
    VSTACK({"caseA", "caseB", "caseC", "caseD"}, 
      HSTACK(caseA, caseB, caseC, caseD))
  )
```

It returns an error: `#VALUE!` or a wrong result. If I wrap `FILTER` with `MIN`, *which is not really necessary because `FILTER` returns a single value*, it works:

[image: excel output]

Similarly if I wrap `startX`, `endX` with `MIN` it also works.

**Notes**:

- Using `A2:A4` on every where I use the name `a`, provides the same result.
- Using `IFERROR` to prevent `VSTACK/HSTACK` returns a single value in case of error.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a possible bug?

Comment: See why it causes error here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74703086/12634230

Comment: @P.b partially, based on more simplified examples provided by @JosWoolley it happens even when not using `LET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be of benefit to both you and those wishing to help you if you constructed simpler examples to illustrate your points. What's more, use of the *Evaluate Formula* tool might help guide you towards an explanation.

There is no bug here, and the behaviour you are witnessing has always been present in Excel.

With the same entries as yours in `A1:A4`, I will use the following simplified example to explain what is happening:

`=INDEX(H1:H10,FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A4=1))`

Looking at the *Evaluate Formula* tool, you can see that this resolves to:

`=INDEX(H1:H10,{1})`

which is not technically identical to

`=INDEX(H1:H10,1)`

and suggests that `FILTER` is returning an *array*, albeit one comprising only a single value.

For functions which are being instructed to return a *cell value*, there is no issue in this array being passed. This is the case with the example above, which will not error.

However, if we extend it to:

`=SUM(INDEX(H1:H10,FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A4=1)):INDEX(H1:H10,FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A4=1)))`

then, by employing `INDEX` in this way, we are asking it to return a *cell reference*, not a *cell value*, i.e. we are asking

`=SUM(INDEX(H1:H10,{1}):INDEX(H1:H10,{1}))`

to be interpreted as

`=SUM(H1:H1)`

though such constructions do not allow arrays.

`OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are two other functions which can return cell references and which exhibit similar behaviour.

`=OFFSET(H1,1,0)`

and

`=INDIRECT("H"&1)`

are valid, whereas

`=OFFSET(H1,{1},0)`

and

`=INDIRECT("H"&{1})`

are not.

Of course, in all these cases the single-value array can be coerced into a non-array via some function (e.g. `SUM`, `MIN`).

Comment: Thanks Jos for your detail explanation. I suspected something like that at the time it worked with `MIN`. I could not simplified it more because I was not sure about the real root cause. When I saw it happens  using `SEQUENCE` roo, It made me doubt about the real cause on my research.  It also a not documented situation by Microsoft. Usually simplification comes after understanding something not before. SO is a good example of that. For people with less experience is more difficult to explain a problem. Sorry for not being able to simply it more. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you think the reason it fails under this construct: `SEQUENCE(endX-startX+1,, startX)` is the same? Sometimes Excel is able to cast a Boolean to a number but is it not able to cast `{1}` to a scalar? I would assume it, but it seems it is not the way it works. Thanks.

Comment: *Evaluate Formula Tool* is great, but not available for all excel versions. I use Excel Web. It is not available for this version.

Comment: @DavidLeal Good point re `SEQUENCE`. This does not appear to be fit with my explanation re functions which expect cell references. I think the reason that function does not operate as expected with array parameters is due to the fact that, as P.b. pointed out in a comment to a previous post re `TEXTSPLIT`, like that function it's already set up to take a row and a column entry as separate *parameters* within the function.

Comment: Re the *Evaluate Formula* tool not being available in Excel Web, just one more reason I use the Desktop version!

Comment: Sorry Jos, I was looking at the link shared by @P.b in the question, but it is related to another function, not `TEXTSPLIT`.  Are you referring to another question? In case you would like to provide the link. Thank. Agreed it is better to have a desktop version, the thing is that Excel Web is free and maybe there people cannot afford it. I have a desktop version on my work computer, but I use my personal computer for SO. Anyway, this is Microsoft policy that I do not agree with, but it is what it is. In Google Spreadsheets, you don't have such a problem. At work, only Excel is allowed.  Thanks